# CANOpen Multi client Single server SDO communication

Tags: canopen, sdo

As SDO communication is for peer to peer communication.
Is there a way a CANOpen server can communicate with two different clients at same time for same object?

For example:
Node-1 (Server): ID-5, OD:6023h, Length:100 bytes
Node-2 (Client): ID-10
Node-3 (Client): ID-11

Can Node-2 and Node-3 upload 6023h from Node-1 simultaneously?

If not is this a limitation on CANOpen protocol?

Answer (score 2):

There can be only one transmitter for a given CAN identifier, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to resolve bus collisions. Therefore, it's not possible for multiple SDO clients to exist for a single SDO server.

However, one CANopen device can contain/host multiple logical SDO servers, which may allow them to serve multiple SDO clients.

When programmed & configured accordingly, it may also be possible for a CANopen node to act as a gateway, accepting connections from multiple SDO clients and routing them to another SDO server. But I don't know if there is a standard protocol for this.

Again, the main rule is only one transmitter for a given CAN identifier.

Comment: There is a CAN standard for CANopen Gateways under document number CiA 302-7 which includes the routing between multiple CANopen networks. I am not sure if this routing is also applicable for routing between two nodes in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. SDO is a request-response protocol and is inherently one-to-one. If you want to communicate with multiple clients at the same time, use PDOs, which is basically a publish-subscribe protocol.